# Unintentional duplicates emerge in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a shapefile layer set on MultiPolygon consisting of polygons which originally didn't have any duplicates. The polygons were spatially separate but a lot of them had the same ID. I manually merged most of the different polygons with the same ID with the `Merge Selected Features` button.

I did it manually because some of the polygons with the same ID should not be merged, instead I had to give them different `ID`'s. Sadly now all my merges have been deleted: all the duplicates popped up again.

Can anyone tells me how this happened and how to prevent this?

I did link the polygon layer to a database with the `ID`'s but I'm not sure if that's the problem and if so why its a problem and what to do about it.

Comment: Please give some more details: what filetype is the date stored in? There are some limitations for editing in several filetypes. This means you can change geometries (delete polygons for example) but the changes can not be saved. This might be a reason for your problem. But there could be other issues. So please state what filetype you use.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reaction. Its a shape-file and it kept my merges for some weeks before somehow all the merges were undone and all the seperate polygons popped up again in the table. Maybe its not possible to merge polygons which are spatialy not connected yet have the same ID?

Comment: Are you working on a shared computer? Is it possible that someone else opened this QGIS project and made changes? Do you have some type of file backup system that might have reverted to an old version of the shapefile? Is the data stored locally or on a server or on a file sharing service like Dropbox or Google Drive? (What you describe is not normal behavior for a shapefile in QGIS, so I'm trying to consider possible outside causes.)

Comment: Hey csk, thanks for your reply, good questions. Im not working on a shared computer and i am the only one using qgis here. Its stored on a server which with other documents never reverts it back to older documents so I guess its not that. The only reason i can think of is that when linking the polygon map with a a table via the unique ID's, the unique ID's that represented multiple polygons duplicate.